# Stored procedure that handles dynamic error code

Tags: mysql

I need a MySql stored procedure that ignores a specific error that I decide at runtime. I tried this

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE test(IN mySqlState VARCHAR(5))
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE mySqlState
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'ignoring error' AS Message;
    END;
.......
END;
```

But I'm getting a compilation error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mySqlState
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'ignoring error' AS Message;
    E' at line 5
```

If instead of `mySqlState` I give a hardcoded value then all works fine. For instance, if I hardcode '42S02' and do a select from an table that doesn't exists then the procedure compiles and the handling works.
But how can I `call test('42S02');` and get the same behavior?
Can I maybe handle all errors and then decide if the current error code equals my parameter then log the message and ignore it?

Comment: What is the rationale of allowing the caller to pass an argument for the type of error to ignore? Shouldn't the procedure code define that explicitly?

Comment: Note that the tag [tag:plsql] is specific to Oracle database, but you have tagged this question MySQL.

Comment: You can use [`GET DIAGNOSTICS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/get-diagnostics.html) within a general conditional handler.

Comment: There's an example on that page that shows how you can write a handler for any `SQLEXCEPTION` and get the diagnostic code into a variable.

Comment: @BillKarwin - This procedure would do something like for ex. "create/delete/rename index/column/constraint/table/etc if it doesn't exist"

Comment: Why don't you check INFORMATION_SCHEMA first, before attempting to do one of those statements?

Comment: There are too many possibilities to consider in my situation, this is the quickest way and is good enough for what I need